# Account is restricted while integrating paypal in my wordpress site with PAID MEMBERSHIP PRO

Tags: paypal, wordpress

I wanted to make membership content for my website.

I used paid membership pro plugin to achieve this.

I signed up with paypal and generated API Credentials.

Now when I want to add new user in that membership level, but getting **Account is restricted** when trying to signup.

Is there any fix to this problem.

Comment: You PayPal account is restricted. https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/helpcenter/article/?articleID=94032

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like your account is in a limited status, which generally just means they want you to provide some documentation to authenticate yourself as the owner of your bank accounts and your PayPal account.

Just login to your PayPal account and you should see messages about the limitation with instructions on how to lift it.